# Passing mutable struct to mutable attribute of struct

Tags: rust

I'm building a small TUI tool with [ratatui](https://github.com/ratatui-org/ratatui), I want to pass a mutable instance of `App` to every widget so I can:

- Handle events and update `widget` data
- Update main `App` data

Here is a simple structure of my tool

```
// app.rs
impl App {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            user_input: UserInput::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn get_curr_widgets(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut dyn Component> {
        vec![
            &mut self.sidebar,
            &mut self.user_input,
        ]
    }
}

// src/components/user_input.rs
impl Component for UserInput {
    fn handle_events(&mut self, event: Event, app: &mut App) {
        match event {
            Event::Key(key_event) => match key_event.code {
                // Update App data
                // KeyCode::Enter => app.do_search(),
                // app.widget_index = -1
                KeyCode::Char(to_insert) => {
                    // Update UserInput data
                    self.enter_char(to_insert);
                }
                _ => {}
            },
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}

// event_handles.rs
pub fn handle_terminal_events(event: Event, app: &mut App) {
    let widget_index = app.widget_index;
    let widgets = app.get_widgets();
    for (index, widget) in app.get_widgets().into_iter().enumerate() {
        if widget_index == index {
            // Error: error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*app` as mutable more than once at a time
            widget.handle_events(event, app);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Full error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*app` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/handler.rs:51:43
   |
48 |         let widgets = app.get_widgets();
   |                     --------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
51 |                 widget.handle_events(event, app);
   |                      -------------        ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                      |
   |                      first borrow later used by call
```

What I think of the error at line: `widget.handle_events(event, app);`

- `widget.` first borrow mutable of `App`
- then we can't pass the second mutable of `App` to the function

In Rust, we only can have one mutable ref at a time.
So what are better ways to solve my problem or I'm structuring it wrong?

Comment: `Rc<RefCell<App>>` gets you shared mutability by doing the borrow checking at runtime instead of build time.

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`, as well as a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @isaactfa `RefCell` will leave it mutably borrowed, which is equivalent to not having access to `App` at all.

Comment: Why does the widget need access to the `App`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I added full error, `App` hold application data/ state and I want to update that rendering later, e.g bellow `// Update App data` in the code

Comment: Do widgets need access to other widgets? If not, the right way is to split `App` into two structs, `AppWidgets` and `AppData`, and only pass a reference to `AppData` to the widgets. If they do, this is a hard problem, but there are also solutions.

Comment: It worked @ChayimFriedman, init and pass AppData like this `pub fn handle_terminal_events(event: Event, app: &mut App, state: &mut AppState) {`. There is currently no communication between widgets, but I think I might need it in the future.

Comment: So are you satisified with this solution?

Comment: Yes, I'll check it more and update the solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This smells like a design problem.
Widgets (Components) are enclosed within App but you are trying to mutate the app when handling events at the Component level.

Ideally the code that mutates the App should exist within the "impl App" block.

```
impl App {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            user_input: UserInput::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn handle_events(&mut self) {
        let mut widgets = vec![
            &mut self.sidebar,
            &mut self.user_input,
        ];
        for (index, widget) in self.get_widgets().iter_mut().enumerate() {
            if widget_index == index {
                widget.handle_events(event, self);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// src/components/user_input.rs
impl Component for UserInput {
    fn handle_events(&mut self, event: Event, app: &mut App) {
        match event {
            Event::Key(key_event) => match key_event.code {
                // Update App data
                // KeyCode::Enter => app.do_search(),
                // app.widget_index = -1
                KeyCode::Char(to_insert) => {
                    // Update UserInput data
                    self.enter_char(to_insert);
                }
                _ => {}
            },
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}

// event_handles.rs
pub fn handle_terminal_events(event: Event, app: &mut App) {
    app.handle_events();
}
```

So by this change you are mutating the app within the context(lifetime) of App impl only.

This should resolve the issue.

NOTE: get methods are conventionally used to read(&) not write (&mut).

Comment: Rust still catch `self` in `widget.handle_events(event, self);` with the error: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time

Comment: This is not borrowing self more than once at a time. Examine the following valid code snippet which is simplified for better understanding,

```
fn f(x: &mut i32) {
    g(x);
    *x += 1;
}

fn g(x: &mut i32) {
    *x += 1;
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 4;
    f(&mut x);
    println!("{x}");
}
```